# Azure SQL Server Reload Weekly

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssis-2012

I am trying to understand a couple of points regarding Microsoft's Azure solution.

I have a 15gb database, 26 tables, 66 text files to create those 26 tables, that I need to put into Azure and completely refresh the table data on a weekly basis.

I have created the database locally, structure and data, created the structure in an Azure SQL instance, but am lost on how to use SSIS "in the cloud".

Trying to import text files into the Azure SQL tables, with the text files on my hard is super slow. I can create an Azure Storage Blob, create a container and upload the text files, but that took almost 3 hours to transfer the text files. And that is before importing them into the SQL tables. Which I don't know how to do inside of Azure.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have removed the sign-off because your name is always displayed beneath your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal way in your situation as per my understanding, is to keep files on your local storage and import those using bcp commands. You can create package\s to truncate the table and use bcp to import data into tables. This package\s can be added into scheduled Sql job on you local Sql server to automate the process.